# Imagemagick - pngs onto png

Tags: imagemagick

i've a huge png image (4000x3000, big.png), and i've smaller images (1500x200, small_n.png) .

I'd like to put the small images onto the big.png based on a starting (x,y) parameter.

So, for instance I've the small_1.png with the starting point (300, 200), and this point should represent the top left corner of the image. How can I put the small_1.png onto the big.png knowing the starting point?

I'd like to use imagemagick, or if not possible, any linux commandline tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you can do that as follows:

```
convert large_image.png small_image.png -geometry +300+200 -compose over -composite result.png
```

If you have several small images, you can repeat the same process multiple times in the same command line.

```
convert large_image.png small_image1.png -geometry +X1+Y1 -compose over -composite small_image2.png -geometry +X2+Y2 -compose over -composite result.png
```

If using ImageMagick 7, replace convert with magick.

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#convert

Comment: Thanks, this is a perfect solution.